# How to detect if the internet connection is over WiFi or Ethernet?

Tags: swift, tvos

Is there a way to open network settings programmatically? Closest thing I know is opening the main settings page:

```
let settingsURL = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(settingsURL)
```

I want to be able to detect if the internet connection is over WiFi or Ethernet.

Answer (score 3):

The way to detect this is to look at the name of the network interfaces. For Mac and Apple TV, `en0` and `en1` refer to the wired and wireless interfaces respectively.

Add this to your bridging header (or create one if needed):

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
```

Then use this Swift code to get the information you need:

```
struct Networking {

    enum NetworkInterfaceType: String, CustomStringConvertible {
        case Ethernet = "en0"
        case Wifi = "en1"
        case Unknown = ""

        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .Ethernet:
                return "Ethernet"
            case .Wifi:
                return "Wifi"
            case .Unknown:
                return "Unknown"
            }
        }
    }

    static var networkInterfaceType: NetworkInterfaceType {
        if let name = Networking().getInterfaces().first?.name, let type = NetworkInterfaceType(rawValue: name) {
            return type
        }

        return .Unknown
    }

    static var isConnectedByEthernet: Bool {
        let networking = Networking()
        for addr in networking.getInterfaces() {
            if addr.name == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet.rawValue {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    static var isConnectedByWiFi: Bool {
        let networking = Networking()
        for addr in networking.getInterfaces() {
            if addr.name == NetworkInterfaceType.Wifi.rawValue {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    // Credit to Martin R http://stackoverflow.com/a/34016247/600753 for this lovely code
    // New Swift 3 implementation needed upated to replace unsafepointer calls with .withMemoryRebound
    func getInterfaces() -> [(name : String, addr: String, mac : String)] {

        var addresses = [(name : String, addr: String, mac : String)]()
        var nameToMac = [ String: String ]()

        // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
        var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
        guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return [] }
        guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return [] }

        // For each interface ...
        for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
            let flags = Int32(ptr.pointee.ifa_flags)
            if var addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr {
                let name = String(cString: ptr.pointee.ifa_name)

                // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
                if (flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING) {
                    switch Int32(addr.pointee.sa_family) {
                    case AF_LINK:
                        nameToMac[name] = withUnsafePointer(to: &addr) { unsafeAddr in
                            unsafeAddr.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr_dl.self, capacity: 1) { dl in
                                dl.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: 1) { dll in
                                    let lladdr = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: dll + 8 + Int(dl.pointee.sdl_nlen), count: Int(dl.pointee.sdl_alen))

                                    if lladdr.count == 6 {
                                        return lladdr.map { String(format:"%02hhx", $0)}.joined(separator: ":")
                                    } else {
                                        return nil
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    case AF_INET, AF_INET6:
                        // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                        var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                        if (getnameinfo(addr, socklen_t(addr.pointee.sa_len),
                                        &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                                        nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                            let address = String(cString: hostname)
                            addresses.append( (name: name, addr: address, mac : "") )
                        }
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

        // Now add the mac address to the tuples:
        for (i, addr) in addresses.enumerated() {
            if let mac = nameToMac[addr.name] {
                addresses[i] = (name: addr.name, addr: addr.addr, mac : mac)
            }
        }

        return addresses
    }
}
```

Usage is:

```
debugPrint(Networking.networkInterfaceType)
```

Or:

```
switch Networking.networkInterfaceType {
case .Ethernet:
    // do something
    break

case .Wifi:
    // do something else
    break

default:
    break
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a swift 3 update? There are some issues with the UnsafePointer parts

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 12.0+, tvOS 12.0+, macOS 10.14+ and watchOS 5.0+ apps you can use `NWPathMonitor` to solve the problem that you described in your question. Add this code to your `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` implementation (Swift 5.1.3/Xcode 11.3.1):

```
let pathMonitor = NWPathMonitor()
pathMonitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
    if path.status == .satisfied {
        if path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi) {
            print("wifi")
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular) {
            print("cellular")
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.wiredEthernet) {
            print("wiredEthernet")
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.loopback) {
            print("loopback")
        } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.other) {
            print("other")
        }
    } else {
        print("not connected")
    }
}
pathMonitor.start(queue: .global(qos: .background))
```

And don't forget to add `import Network` to the top of the file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Reachability API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

```
let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
(reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value == ReachableViaWiFi.value) // For WiFi
(reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value == ReachableViaWWAN.value) // For WWAN
(reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value == NotReachable.value) // For No Internet
```

Comment: Reachability has no value for Ethernet. It returns ReachableViaWiFi for it instead. I think ReachableViaWiFi should be renamed to ReachableViaLAN or something in this case.

Comment: I agree with @saucewipe . Reachability is not detecting the difference between WiFi and Ethernet.

Comment: Which modules do I have to import for using *Reachability* in Swift?

Comment: You'll have to download and setup Reachability for use from Apple, or else write your own implementation yourself (it's not super tricky -- and there are many on GitHub). I concur with the above comments -- Reachability cannot separate ethernet from wlan, it just tells you wether you're on a wwan connection or not.