Is it possible to detect ethernet adapter cable when connected to iPhone using Xamarin?
I am trying programatically to detect ethernet adapter cable when connected to iPhone in Xamarin Forms but till now whatever I tried is not working on iOS device. Communication is happening between iPhone and device when I connect ethernet cable from device to iPhone using Lightning to ethernet adapter but can't detect when cable connects to iPhone.
Is it possible to achieve this using Xamarin.Forms?
I tried these:
Solution 1:
foreach (NetworkInterface ni in
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
(ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet))
{
return true;
}
}
This is giving true always whether device is connected to ethernet adapter or not.
Solution 2:
using Xamarin.Essentials
if (Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.Ethernet)){
return true
}

This works for android but not for iOS
Solution 3:
var monitor = new NWPathMonitor();
var queue = new CoreFoundation.DispatchQueue("NetworkMonitor");
monitor.SetQueue(queue);
var isEthernetConnected = false;

monitor.SetUpdatedSnapshotHandler((path) =>
{
path.EnumerateInterfaces((ni) =>
{
if(ni.InterfaceType == NWInterfaceType.Wired)
isEthernetConnected = true;
});
});

monitor.Start();

return isEthernetConnected;

when connected to ethernet count of interface is zero so it's also not working in Xamarin iOS platform specific.

As far as I know, this is not doable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315479/how-to-detect-if-the-internet-connection-is-over-wifi-or-ethernet

@Jason I tried swift code in c# but it is not working. How iOS shows ethernet options in Settings screen when ethernet adapter connects to iPhone? Which Api to use for Xamarin? Any specific permission to give in iPhone app?

This cannot achieve on the IOS device. You can check this thread about Is there a way to detect that a USB Ethernet Adapter is connected to an iPhone/iPad?
